# Assertion coverage and assertions count in industry

Tags: coverage, quality-assessment

I have recently found one of my test is verifying only 3 of 10 fields of entity modified by the system under test.

I've added a couple of more assertions to the same tests. That obviously hasn't increased line coverage or branch coverage. Is there a way to measure oracles quality?

In research papers I found two related metrics:

- **assertion coverage**/**checked coverage**: percentage of statements directly covered by the assertions, proposed in ["Assessing Oracle Quality with Checked Coverage"](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/publications/files/schuler-icst-2011.pdf)
- **assertions count** proposed in ["Assertions Are Strongly Correlated with Test Suite Effectiveness"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1079.4905&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

but that's research and I couldn't find any tooling for measuring/reporting them for Python.

Are those metrics used in industry?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is mutation testing.

From the [Pitest website](https://pitest.org/):

> Mutation testing is conceptually quite simple.
>
> Faults (or mutations) are automatically seeded into your code, then
> your tests are run. If your tests fail then the mutation is killed, if
> your tests pass then the mutation lived.
>
> The quality of your tests can be gauged from the percentage of
> mutations killed.

Pitest is for JVM, but most main programming languages have mature tools for it.

For more details, I suggest [this talk by the Pitest main developer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoFJajoJQ2g).

Comment: Thanks, this seems more practical are there seems to be more tooling for that, e.g. [mutmut](https://github.com/boxed/mutmut) for Python.

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer is satisfactory, could you mark is as accepted?